# "(Gehören) in" mit Akkusativ oder Dativ?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, dative, accusative

Welcher Satz ist richtig?

Frage mit *Wohin?* (Akkusativ):

> Der Müll gehört in die Mülltonne.
>   Wohin gehört der Müll?

oder Frage mit *Wo?* (Dativ):

> Der Müll gehört in der Mülltonne.
>   Wo gehört der Müll?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Der Akkusativ ist richtig:

> Der Müll gehört in die Mülltonne.

Beachte aber, dass nur die Richtungsangabe im Akkusativ steht. Das Subjekt (hier: der Müll) ist immer Nominativ. Die Frage muss also heißen:

> Wohin gehört **der** Müll?

Comment: Splitten ist auch möglich: "Wo gehört der Müll hin?"

Comment: Vielleicht könnte man noch ein Wort zum Dativ erwähnen ("Der Müll gehört dem Peter").

Comment: Oder besser: "Der Müll gehört Peter"

Comment: @TaW Da sieht man aber keinen Kasus. ;)

Comment: Nein, aber es ist halt gutes Deutsch  ;-)  - "Dem Peter sein Müll" kann man auch sagen, aber bitte nicht schreiben

Comment: Was ist die richtige Lösung? Ich habe es nicht verstanden.

Comment: Was hast du nicht verstanden? Brauchst du eine Antwort in Englisch? Would it help to have an answer in English?

Comment: @TaW Ob das mit oder ohne Artikel als gutes/gängiges Deutsch angesehen wird, ist ja regional recht unterschiedlich. Als Franke betrachte ich beispielsweise die Aussage "Das Buch gehört dem Peter" nicht als schlechteres Deutsch als "Das Buch gehört Peter".

Comment: Richtig, aber als Franke ist mir aber klar dass es eben Dialekt ist und nicht Hochdeutsch :-)

Comment: @Ahemd: Die richtige Antwort is die erste. Die zweiten Sätze sind falsch.