# Wenfall mit "gehören"

Tags: accusative

> Wenn Frauen wirklich in die Küche gehören, dann gehören Männer in den Keller. <sup>[SOURCE](http://ispruch.de/wenn_frauen_wirklich_in_die_kueche_gehoeren_dann_gehoeren_maenner_in_den_keller_zu_all_dem_anderen_nutzlosen_kram.html)</sup>

Is it standard to use the accusative case with this verb when it is used in this way?

Comment: Can anyone explain why this was down-voted?

Comment: I don't know. A similar question has already been asked before (http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22289/geh%c3%b6ren-mit-akkusativ-oder-dativ), and some people consider that as a reason to downvote the duplicate, but the other question was in German, and repeating a German question in English is considered as acceptable.

Comment: Warum ist der Titel auf Deutsch, die Frage aber auf Englisch?

Answer (score 9):

"gehören" can be used either with a dative object (meaning "to belong to somebody/something")

> "Der Ring gehört meiner Mutter" = "The ring belongs to my mother"

or with a *motion* (not *location*!) specification (meaning "to belong somewhere").

> "Der vergammelte Apfel gehört in den Mülleimer" = "The rotten apple belongs in the garbage can"

Most motion specifications in German have the form "preposition + accusative". So it's not really "gehören" + accusative object (which would be ungrammatical), but "gehören" + motion specification, and the motion specification is "in" + accusative noun.

Comment: I was aware that the accusative is used in "motion specifications", but this didn't seem at all like a motion specification.

Comment: The important bit of information conveyed here is that this is perceived as a "motion specification".  In English one can say women belong in the kitchen, but one would not say women belong "into" the kitchen.

Comment: @MichaelHardy One can say "A gehört in B" both if A is already in B and if A is not (yet) in B but ought to be moved there. It seems that the second aspect (the intended motion) is perceived as more relevant in German.

Comment: If it's already in B, would you use the dative case?

Comment: @MichaelHardy With "in"? No. It's always a motion specification, not a location specification, even if A is already in B. "Gehören zu etwas" uses the dative case, say, "Tiger gehören zu den Großkatzen", but that's because "zu" always requires the dative case.

Comment: There is not really a motion, because you use the same of it is already in the garbage can.

Comment: @CarstenS That's exactly the point. "Gehören" is always used with a grammatical motion specification (*Richtungsangabe*, answering the question "wohin?"), rather than with a location specification (*Ortsangabe*, answering the question "wo?"). This holds even if there is no motion, because the item is already located where it's supposed to be.

Comment: Ah, it makes sense that way, thanks for the clarification. „Er gehört zu mir, wie mein Name an der Tür. [...] Nananaa, Nanaana.“

Answer (score 1):

Deine Frage scheint zu unterstellen, dass *gehören* in dieser Konstruktion ein Akkusativobjekt hat. Das ist nicht der Fall. *Gehören* kann ausschließlich mit einem Dativobjekt verwendet werden: *jemandem gehören.* Beispiel:

> Das Spielzeug gehört dem Hund.
> <del>Das Spielzeug gehört den Hund.</del>

Dein Beispielsatz ist aus Gesichtspunkten der politischen Korrektheit fragwürdig, deswegen nehme ich stattdessen folgenden Vergleichbaren:

> Wildschweine gehören in den Wald.

Hier hat das Verb *gehören* **kein Objekt.** Stattdessen wird es mit einer Lokaladverbiale ergänzt. Diese Lokaladverbiale sagt aus, *wo* etwas richtigerweise sein soll. Semantisch kann man davon ausgehen, dass das Subjekt des Satzes sich wahrscheinlich nicht dort befindet, wo es sein soll, weswegen die Lokaladverbiale eine Bewegung ausdrückt. (Der vorangegangene Satz ist aus etymologischen Gesichtspunkten sicherlich Humbug, aber mag als Volksetymologie noch tragbar sein.) Die Bewegung wird durch einen Akkusativ nach der Präposition ausgedrückt:

> Wildschweine gehören *in den Wald.*
>
> Rinder gehören *auf die Weide.*
>
> Das Essen gehört *auf den Teller.*

Die Präposition *in/auf/etc.* gehört notwendigerweise mit zum Fragment dazu.